# JPanel does not displayed on JFrame

Tags: java, swing

Problem - the given codes below is not displaying my JPanel(PageOne) and I am not sure why is it not displaying my JPanel(PageOne). Please Help.

I have added the JPanel(PageOne) to my panel which has a cardLayout();
I have set my JFrame to visible already.

PageOne.java

```
   import javax.swing.JLabel;
   import javax.swing.JPanel;

   public class PageOne extends JPanel {

    public PageOne() {
         JLabel label = new JLabel("Page 1");
         JPanel panel = new JPanel();
         panel.add(label);
   }    }
```

PageTwo.java

```
   import javax.swing.JLabel;
   import javax.swing.JPanel;

   public class PageTwo extends JPanel {

    public PageTwo() {
         JLabel label = new JLabel("Page 2");
         JPanel panel = new JPanel();
         panel.add(label);
       }
   }
```

DisplayUI.java

```
   import java.awt.CardLayout;
   import javax.swing.JFrame;  
   import javax.swing.JPanel;
   import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

   public class DisplayUI {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
           new DisplayUI();
    }

       public DisplayUI() {
           SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
           @Override
               public void run() {
                  CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();
                   JFrame frame = new JFrame("frame");
                   JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                   panel.setLayout(cardLayout);    
                   panel.add(new PageOne(), "1");
                   panel.add(new PageTwo(), "2");
                   cardLayout.show(panel,"1");
                   frame.add(panel);
                   frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                   frame.pack();
                   frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                   frame.setVisible(true);
               }
           });
       }
   }
```

Comment: This code seems to be both extending `JPanel` and using a `JPanel` as an instance.  Do one or the other.  If fact, don't extend `JPanel` unless necessary (it isn't).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not actually adding anything to `PageOne` or `PageTwo` panels...

```
public PageOne() {
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Page 1");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.add(label);
    // But nothing is actually added to "this"...
}
```

Unless you "really" need it, you can get rid of the second `JPanel` and add the `label` directly to `PageOne` (and the same thing goes for `PageTwo`)

```
public PageOne() {
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Page 1");
    add(label);
}
```

Or add the `JPanel` you create (which contains the label)

```
public PageOne() {
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Page 1");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.add(label);
    add(panel);
}
```

Remember, `JPanel` is type of `Container`, it can have child components.

Answer (score 0):

Get the content pane of frame and than try adding :

```
Container container=frame.getContentPane();
container.add(panel);
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Since Java 1.5, `add` redirects to `getContentPane().add` automatically